# Profiling Plone/Zope

Tags: plone, zope

What is current best practice for profiling Plone/Zope applications on a Plone 4.1/Zope 2.13 system?

**Products.ZopeProfiler** and the Plone.org version of **CallProfiler** both fail at install time with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/derek/plone4/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.10-py2.6.egg/OFS/Application.py", line 689, in install_product
    initmethod(context)
  File "/home/derek/plone4/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.ZopeProfiler-2.0.1-py2.6.egg/Products/ZopeProfiler/__init__.py", line 8, in initialize
    control_panel = context._ProductContext__app.Control_Panel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Control_Panel'
```

**z3c.profiler** wants to install a lot of apparently-incompatible dependencies (not surprising since it's intended for Zope3).

**collective.profiler** looks promising, and installs, but doesn't let me profile the `__call__` method of a View, because the method doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute.

Comment: Apparently CallProfiler has been fixed since I asked, to at least install and it seems to atually profile calls.  Unfortunately it fails on most attempts to display the results.

Comment: I have released Products.CallProfiler on pypi but it suffer of the same bug. wait for the new release of those packages

Comment: Have a look at the Monitoring section of http://scalingplone.pbworks.com/w/page/3770062/Tuning for some notes regarding ZODB activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [repoze.profile](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/repoze.profile) and it's [documentation](http://docs.repoze.org/profile/). It runs as WSGI middleware component which aggregates profiling data across all requests to the WSGI application.

Comment: Isn't this wsgi specific?  I'm not using wsgi

Answer (score 0):

The ZopeProfiler in Version 2.0.2 works just fine with Plone 4.1